# Select Statements based on Variable

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am sure this should be something quite simple but I cant work out the syntax.

I have a variable called domain this can be either populated or not, when it is populated I want to run one statement but when its not I want to run a different one.  I would say it should be something like in a very simplistic form.

```
IF @Domain = '.co.uk'

select * from table where domain = @domain

else

select * from table

end
```

Not sure if that is enough to give someone something to start with.

Thanks P

---

Thought it might be better to post the exact code I am using as this may alter some of the responses and make things a bit easier to explain.

The code shown below is the exact one I will be running and to be fair the case based on the variable might be easier on the join rather than 2 select statements.

```
select affiliate_id
      ,campaign_id
      ,count(*) as leads
from [BDatabase]..affil a (nolock)
where cast(created_datetime as date) between @startdate and @enddate
    and (a.domain = @domain
        or isnull(@Domain,'') = ''
        )
group by affiliate_id
        ,campaign_id
```

Comment: I think there needs to be clarification here for all the answers that are combining the two example queries you have used.  Are you running to completely unrelated scripts or - as per your question - do you want to have conditional filtering based on the values in variables/parameters?

Comment: Hi all,  I thought it might be better to post the exact code I am using as this may alter some of the responses and make things a bit easier to explain.  The code shown below is the exact one I will be running and to be fair the case based on the variable might be easier on the join rather than 2 select statements,,  `select affiliate_id
, campaign_id
, count(*) as leads
from [BDatabase]..affil a (nolock) 
where cast(created_datetime as date) between @startdate and @enddate
and (a.domain = @domain or isnull(@Domain,'') = '')
group by affiliate_id, campaign_id`

Comment: Your current query looks as it if is handling the `@domain` value as required?  Can you post some sample data and the current and expected result of your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE domain = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Domain,'') = '' THEN domain ELSE @Domain END
```

As per your your edited query pasted you can use above solution as below

```
select affiliate_id
      ,campaign_id
      ,count(*) as leads
from [BDatabase]..affil a (nolock)
where cast(created_datetime as date) between @startdate and @enddate
    and a.domain = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@domain,'') = '' THEN a.domain ELSE @domain END              
group by affiliate_id
        ,campaign_id
```

Comment: As long as the requirement for `@domain = '.co.uk'` was just an example, this is the best solution (which I often use myself). Not only does it check for `NULL`, it only checks for empty string and treats it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table 
where (domain = @domain and @Domain = '.co.uk') 
or (@domain is null or @domain='')
```